# Executing a method in Java after either prior asynchronous methods are done?

Tags: java, completable-future

I'm trying to use Completetable future to run two task in async. The program runs asynchronously, such that a() and b() run first, in any order, concurrently. But c() can only run after either one of a() or b() completes

```
class Pair{
  public void pair2() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    CompletableFuture<Void> fa = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> a());
    CompletableFuture<Void> fb = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> b());

    if(fa.isDone || fb.isDone){ //should not be if loop.
      c();
    }
    return;
  }

  public void a(){
    System.out.println("I'm a.");
    return;
  }
  public void b(){
    System.out.println("I'm b.");
    return; 
  }

  public void c(){
    System.out.println("I'm c, I cannot be the first!");
    return;
  }
}
```

I'm not familiar with the CompletableFuture API, is there a way to check if either of the task is done and call upon the next method C?

Comment: Does `if(fa.isDone())` work?

Comment: No unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use one of the `xxxEither` methods. For example:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> fc = fa.acceptEither(fb, v -> c());
```

Or you could use the `anyOf` method:

```
CompletableFuture.anyOf(fa, fb).thenRun(this::c);
```

Comment: This works! Is a reason why isDone doesn't? And if it is wrong to use isDone?

Comment: @Carrein `isDone` returns immediately - so in your example, it's likely that the tasks haven't finished yet and it returns false.